# HCE android:apduServiceBanner attribute for tap and pay - does it have to be 260 X 96 dp

Tags: android, hce, android-tap-and-pay

Per the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html) the android:apduServiceBanner for tap and pay icon should be  260 X 96 dp ? So what folder should i put this image in ? should i place it in mdpi ? What if i want to add icons for each density myself, is it ok ? Please if you can help me decide which android folder to put the service banner icon. I've tried putting the graphic into mdpi but i want to know what is the recommended way.

> > Required assets for payment applications
>
> To provide a more visually attractive user experience, HCE payment
>   applications are required to provide an additional asset for their
>   service: a so-called service banner.
>
> This asset should be sized 260x96 dp, and can be specified in your
>   meta-data XML file by adding the `android:apduServiceBanner` attribute
>   to the `<host-apdu-service>` tag, which points to the drawable resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, those are the correct dimensions.

```
apduServiceBanner should be 260x96 dp. In pixels, that works out to...
  - drawable-xxhdpi: 780x288 px
  - drawable-xhdpi:  520x192 px
  - drawable-hdpi:   390x144 px
  - drawable-mdpi:   260x96  px
```

Reference: [Android Card Emulation Reference Application](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-CardEmulation/blob/a432dae2a40e64a3253c0d88e7d8e5d7655d34b6/Application/src/main/res/xml/aid_list.xml)